# How can every items in ItemsControl auto scaling?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I need to use a `ItemsControl` in the project. I wanna that not only every items in `ItemsControl` can auto scaling,but also every items in `ItemsControl` has the same size.

So I decide to use a `ViewBox` to do it.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" StretchDirection="UpOnly">
    <ItemsControl Name="FunctionButton" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button>
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid Background="#00008000" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.60*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Ellipse Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                    Fill="#44474c" Name="E"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonName}" 
                                    Grid.Column="2" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Foreground="#575757" 
                                    FontSize="13" 
                                    Margin="0,10"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="E" 
                                                    To="#a4cbd0" 
                                                    Duration="00:00:01"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="E" 
                                                    To="#44474c" 
                                                    Duration="00:00:01"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

And here is code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FunctionButton.ItemsSource = FunctionButtonList;
    FunctionButtonClass FBC = new FunctionButtonClass();
    FBC.ButtonName = "123";
    FunctionButtonList.Add(FBC);
    FBC = new FunctionButtonClass();
    FBC.ButtonName = "4546465";
    FunctionButtonList.Add(FBC);
    FBC = new FunctionButtonClass();
    FBC.ButtonName = "34534534534";
    FunctionButtonList.Add(FBC);
}

public class FunctionButtonClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    string _ButtonName;
    public string ButtonName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ButtonName;
        }
        set
        {
            _ButtonName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("ButtonName");
        }
    }            
}

List<FunctionButtonClass> FunctionButtonList = new List<FunctionButtonClass>();
```

Well, after the programme ran, it turned out to be this:
[image]

The third one missing the ellipse,and the ellipse of first one and second one seems not the same size.

What's wrong with my code? How can I make every items in `ItemsControl` the same size? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of a StackPanel, use a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel.

Comment: This is just additional info based on Clemens's comment. Items in `StackPanel` will get only the space that they need, while `Grid` will allocate the same space for every element in it's collection. What you are using here will assign only the space that the controls require while `Grid` or `UniformGrid` will give each `control` the same amount of space.

Comment: @Clemens However,I tried to use <UniformGrid Columns="1"></UniformGrid> to replace <StackPanel/> as ItemsPanel,but the question still remains.

Comment: I tried to use UniformGrid instead of StackPanel,but it is no use.@XAMlMAX .

Answer (score 0):

If u want any control to start with the same conditions like height etc, u can change ur `Application.xaml`. If u do that every control get the same *start values* if u dont change it manually. I guess ur ellipse should be fine then.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property=""
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: But I want every items in ItemsControl has the same size after auto scaling,but not just when the programme starts.